# Issue specifying ComputerName in Start-Job scriptblock

Tags: powershell

Here's a script I'm trying to run, where $servers = @("computer1","computer2")

```
$servers | % {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($c) Get-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Newest 10 -ComputerName $c} -ArgumentList $_
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the jobs will stay "running".  I thought perhaps this was an issue with passing parameters, so I removed that portion of the script, like so-

```
$servers | % {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($c) Get-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Newest 10} -ArgumentList $_
}
```

... and it worked.  I then tried to specify the computername (to validate it was a parameter passing issue), like so -

```
$servers | % {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($c) Get-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Newest 10 -ComputerName "computer1"} -ArgumentList $_
}
```

The expected effect would be for it to get remote events on the same server twice.  Instead I experienced the same issue as before: the script starts 2 jobs which both stay in a running state for... ever.

Any ideas or pointers?

Quick Edit:

I did also try to just use Get-EventLog on the remote machine without trying to run it in a job.  That works fine.

Final Edit:

From Keith's response it looks like the issue is in my environment.  I'll troubleshoot further on my own and accept Keith's answer as it pointed me to that conclusion.

Comment: How do you know they stay in a running state?

Comment: @splatteredbits I think just typing `get-job` and readig the 'state' coloumn.

Comment: Christian is right... I can tell the state of a job by... checking the state of jobs with the Get-Job cmdlet.

Comment: Why don't you pass directly to `-argumentlist` the `$servers` variable?

Comment: Wouldn't that end up with one Get-EventLog cmdlet running against two servers sequentially?  If it even worked?  I'll give it a try later.

Comment: Does it fail if you execute just `Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Newest 10 -ComputerName computer1}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I can't repro this error on either PowerShell V2 or V3:

```
8# 'build3','build5' | %{ Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($c) Get-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Newest 10 -Comput
erName $c} -ArgumentList $_}

Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------
5               Job5            Running    True            localhost            param($c)...
7               Job7            Running    True            localhost            param($c)...


9# Get-Job

Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------
1               Job1            Failed     False           localhost            param($c)...
3               Job3            Completed  False           localhost            param($c)...
5               Job5            Completed  True            localhost            param($c)...
7               Job7            Completed  True            localhost            param($c)...


10# Receive-Job -id 5

   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
 1397893 Jul 20 15:47  Warning     Group Policy Inte...   2248216579 The description for Event ID '-2046750717' in S...
 1397892 Jul 20 15:47  Warning     Group Policy Regi...   2248216579 The description for Event ID '-2046750717' in S...
```

It could be configuration issue. Do you have the Remote Registry service running on the servers?  Also, you can run Receive-Job on the jobs even while they're running to get intermediate output & errors.  Perhaps some error info would help track down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, Keith.  Remote registry is running.  If I take out the $c and replace it with either of the computer names in the list I'm trying to check, it works fine so I don't expect that it's a config issue on a remote machine.  I've even tried running it from another source server in the environment.

Answer (score 1):

What about using this ?

```
$servers = @("computer1","computer2")

$servers | ForEach-Object {$comp = $_
           Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Newest 10 -ComputerName $input} -InputObject $comp}
```

Comment: The solution I need is for local multitasking only.  WinRM setup is out of scope for my present work.  This very well may work for many cases though.

Comment: I am not sure I understand then what you are trying to do, why do you have $servers = @("computer1","computer2") if you are not trying to run it against multiple computers. Could you explain exactly what you would like the it to do and i can try help.

Comment: I'm running it against multiple computers, not on multiple computers.  Invoke command will actually start the job on another machine.  My solution will start mutiple Get-EventLog commands on the local machine which will run concurrently.

Comment: Ok I have changed the code try with this and let me know if it works

Comment: Same behavior.  Stuck at "running"